# VB.NET Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to DataBase

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to add data to a bind Datagridview to a table. But can't do anything and checked more than 30 websites without any solution ...

I'm on Visual Studio 2019 using vb.net code.
And here's the code returning the error.

```
Private Sub TextBox_NBScan_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox_NBScan.TextChanged
    ' ajoute chaque code scanné dans la table provisoir pour la sortie de stock en cours
    If TextBox_NBScan.Text = "" Then

    Else
        ' Permet d'ajouter les données au DG si elle n'est pas connectée (bind) avec la DB
        ' Me.DG_Sortie.Rows.Add(TextBox_NBScan.Text, "1", Today)
        Me.Sortie_StockTableAdapter.Fill(TextBox_NBScan.Text)
        Me.DG_Sortie.Update()
    End If

End Sub
```

I just want to add data from the textbox directly to the Datagridview (bind to the table "Sortie_Stock")

I'm completely new on dev project, this is my first one ! :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The TableAdapter fill command is reading data from the database, it cannot accept text because it is expecting to read a datatable.

Use the TableAdapter Insert command to add data.  Update to change data or the Delete to remove data.
     Me.Sortie_StockTableAdapter.Insert(TextBox_NBScan.Text);
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/directly-access-the-database-with-a-tableadapter?view=vs-2019